# How to attach the rigged wheels to the car body and make them move left and right?

Tags: rigging

i rigged the wheel but don't know how to attach it to the body of the car and move them left and right like front wheels do in real car. I searched everywhere but can't find the tutorial.

[image: Useless Rigged wheel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an empty at the end of Bone.002 and make it the child of Bone. Put Inverse Kinematics constraint on Bone.002 and choose the Empty as a target.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xxB8mxmHnnE0CvzsjuIFUC7xsNWNQ-v2

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to go about it. Though you might be required to do some tweaking. Check it out here https://gachoki.com/how-to-rig-a-car-in-2-minutes-in-blender-2-83/

Comment: Links to answers are not answers, if the link goes down your answer becomes empty and meaningless. Either transcribe essential parts of the process here or post these as comments instead.